# Python ModuleNotFoundError when run a single module in my project

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, modulenotfounderror

I have a project dir structure as:

```
.
└── project
    ├── a
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── aa.py
    ├── b
    │   └── bb
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       └── bbb.py
    └── __init__.py
```

In `bbb.py`:

```py
from project.a import aa
...
```

When I import any my module from `.`, it succeeds.
However, if I run a single module such as `bbb.py` from `.`, it shows ModuleNotFoundError;

```sh
$ python3 -i project/b/bb/bbb.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/project/b/bb/bbb.py", line 1, in <module>
    from project.a import aa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
>>>
```

I already know these solutions; **add sys.path**, **export PYTHONPATH**, and **pip install my project**. They are not what I want to know.

Here is my question: If python does not understand my module structure in that way, is that right way to import my module? If it is proper way to express my module structure, why python works like that (show error when run single module)? Also, what is the *pythonic* and *fundamental* way to run a single module in the project. I am open to any other suggestion to debug a single module.

Comment: Can you show the full error traceback?

Comment: Where do you import from?

Comment: @AdamJenča, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'`
@HamidrezaKhorammfar, When I import as above in `.` (project root directory), is got an error.
I added some details in the text.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell python to run it as a module or else it won't know how to look for it properly by passing the `-m` flag:

Here is my directory setup

```
project
├── __init__.py
├── a
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── aa.py
└── b
    ├── __init__.py
    └── bb
        ├── __init__.py
        └── bbb.py
```

And then you have to run it as a module itself like so. Also note how I'm calling it differently instead of passing the path, I path how it would look as a module in a Python file. I am also running this from the directory that contains the `project` folder not inside the `project` folder itself :

```
$ python -im project.b.bb.bbb
>>> exit()
```

Here is the contents of `bbb.py`

```
from project.a import aa
```

Here is the description of the flag itself from the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m)

> -m 
> Search sys.path for the named module and execute its contents as the **main** module.
>
> Since the argument is a module name, you must not give a file extension (.py). The module name should be a valid absolute Python module name, but the implementation may not always enforce this (e.g. it may allow you to use a name that includes a hyphen).
>
> Package names (including namespace packages) are also permitted. When a package name is supplied instead of a normal module, the interpreter will execute .**main** as the main module. This behaviour is deliberately similar to the handling of directories and zipfiles that are passed to the interpreter as the script argument.
>
> Note This option cannot be used with built-in modules and extension modules written in C, since they do not have Python module files. However, it can still be used for precompiled modules, even if the original source file is not available.
>
> If this option is given, the first element of sys.argv will be the full path to the module file (while the module file is being located, the first element will be set to "-m"). As with the -c option, the current directory will be added to the start of sys.path.

Comment: Thanks. So, you are meaning that I am using python module system in right way and one thing I should do is that run python with notifying them which is the root of project, am I right?

Comment: Yeah you have it setup correctly you just need to let the python interpreter know that you are running it as a module so it knows to set the `PYTHONPATH` properly to make all your imports work

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. How people debug their single python module? I was trying to use debug mode in vs code, but it showed the above error so I asked. Can you recommend the common and easy way to debug? I usually use `python -i` mode.

Comment: debugging is a large topic that's outside the scope of this question unfortunately